# Does Eli Mandel's poem about Auschwitz contain a rare word, or a typo?

Tags: poetry, misprint, eli-mandel

I read in *The New Oxford Book of Canadian Verse in English* (1982)
Eli Mandel's poem *On the 25th Anniversary of the Liberation of Auschwitz: Memorial Services, Toronto, January 25th, 1970 YMHA Bloor and Spadina*.

One of the last lines runs as follows:

> while the whitehatted star spangled cowboys
>     shot the dark men and shot the dark men
>     and we threw popcorn balls and grabbed
>     each other and cheered:
> the lowheach other and cheered:
>             me jewboy yelling
> for the shot town and the falling men

Does 'lowheach' mean something, or is it simply a typo? I could easily believe that the line was intended to run, '*something* each other' but I have no idea what *something* would be, and I've been unable to find another copy of the poem. The poem was written in 1973; long enough that a rare word could have vanished, but I'm betting on a typo.

Comment: There's clearly a line repeated with addition in the beginning, a weird misprint. This could not be OK.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The original 1973 publication of the poem is available at the Internet Archive and reads as follows:

> while the whitehatted star spangled cowboys
>         shot the dark men and shot the dark men
>         and we threw popcorn balls and grabbed
>         each other and cheered:
>                                                   me jewboy yelling
> for the shot town and the falling men
>
> <sub>Eli Mandel (1973). [*Stony Plain*, p. 69](https://archive.org/details/stonyplain0000mand/page/68/mode/2up). Erin, Ontario: press porcépic.</sub>

Other reprints of the poem have the same wording, for example, [*15 Canadian poets plus 5* (1978) p. 234](https://archive.org/details/15canadianpoetsp0000unse/page/234/mode/2up); [*The Oxford Anthology of Canadian Literature* (1981), p. 324](https://archive.org/details/oxfordanthologyo0000unse/page/324/mode/2up); [*The Spice Box: An Anthology of Jewish Canadian Writing* (1981), p. 120](https://archive.org/details/spiceboxantholog0000unse/page/120/mode/2up).

So *The New Oxford Book of Canadian Verse in English* has a misprint, as you surmised.

Comment: Thanks! So not only a typo, but an extra line; worse than I'd expected.